# Execution script bat using control-M

Tags: batch-file, ssis, control-m

i have case regarding control-M.
I have simple script batch and plan execute using control-M job, below detail script :

1.MasterParam.bat

```
@echo

Set PathPackage=D:\test\
```

2.Main.bat

```
@echo off

Set PackageName=Package.dtsx
Call MasterParam.bat
Dtexec /f %PathPackage%%PackageName%
If %errorlevel% NEQ 0 ( exit /b %errorlevel%)
```

Question :

1. Can control-M execution script.bat with containing Call another scritp.bat?
2. wheter control-M stop the job if script.bat return errorlevel !=0?

Comment: I don't understand why you ask programmers on Stack Overflow if the batch file executed most likely by `cmd.exe` started by *Contorl-M* works as expected by you. Try it out and you know it. Well, it would be most likely better to replace `Call MasterParam.bat` by `call "%~dp0MasterParam.bat"` if `MasterParam.bat` is stored in same directory as `Main.bat`. Then it does not matter which directory is the current directory on execution of `Main.bat`. The last but one line should be better `Dtexec /f "%PathPackage%%PackageName%"` whereby `Dtexec` should be specified with full qualified file name.

Comment: A full qualified file name consists of drive + path + name + extension enclosed in double quotes, at least on containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~``. The last line is better `if errorlevel 1 exit /B` which results in exiting the batch file execution on `dtexec` exits with a value greater or equal 1 indicating an error condition and same exit code is passed by command `exit` to `cmd.exe` processing the batch file which exits with same exit code for parent process which is here *Control-M*.

Comment: `MasterParam.bat` should have as first line `@echo off` and not just `@echo` which outputs the current status of command echo mode.

Comment: Thanks mofi for the respon. Fyi i already tested run the script by cmd.exe and its ok. i am not install control-M yet on my laptop cause my client doesnt give me privilage to install software anything. So i just wanna to make sure if i run main.bat and call masterparam.bat on control-M job running well. And make sure if the package error control-M job stop process with error

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the original answers, note that you can run Control-M jobs as direct commands (instead of executing .bat or .cmd files) which is often a better way to control the task (and works fine with dtexec /F ...).

Answer (score -1):

If %errorlevel% NEQ 0  command means  Not Equal to 0 and yes control-M  can stop the job if script.bat return errorlevel !=0
By using Call MasterParam.bat or even by Call MasterParam
u can also pass parameters while calling the script -Calls one batch program from another without stopping the parent batch program. The call command accepts labels as the target of the call.